Etre fleur bleue
To which flower are we referring to when we say "être fleur(flower) bleue"?
By googling it, I might refer to "la fleur du paradis" but I am not sure. Any explanation is welcome as much as the meaning of the flower in flower language.

It is the flower for which Heinrich longs in a dream, the cheesiest passage (among a host of hilarious contenders) from Novalis' eponymous novel. It has a a reasonably well written entry in en.WP.
Novalis did not specify the botanical species of the flower and it is pointless to debate which one, if any, he had in mind.
However, so many Romanticists reflected on the symbol that some of them must have grown their own idea. I recall a specific paragraph from Nerval's Aurélia, which can be read as identifying Novalis' Blue Flower with the forget-me-not:

Sur les montagnes de l'Hymalaya une petite fleur est née. - Ne
m'oubliez pas! - Le regard chatoyant d'une étoile s'est fixé un
instant sur elle, et une réponse s'est fait entendre dans un doux
langage étranger. - Myosotis!

I do not know if the novella has a decent English translation; comments for suggestions most welcome.
